# Need a pivot function for showing branch Wise Item total Stock qty ( Branch as Column , Item as Row and sum of Sock Qty as Data)

Tags: sql

[image: Pivot]

Need a pivot function for showing branch Wise Item total Stock qty ( Branch as Column , Item as Row and sum of Sock Qty as Data)

Item is a selection from ItemMaster table  and Branch is a selection from Branch master table  and Stock qty is in Stock table .

Attaching a sample data with this question .

Comment: Does the number of branches change that often? Is it a set number of known branches at the moment? Also, what columns are in each of the 3 tables besides Branch, Item, and Stock qty?

Comment: Yes no of branches is known.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include all of the columns of the tables, I took a stab and guessed at the structure of each includes something like:

**BranchMaster:**

```
+----------+------------+
| BranchId | BranchName |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Branch 1   |
|        2 | Branch 2   |
|        3 | Branch 3   |
+----------+------------+
```

**ItemMaster:**

```
+--------+-----------------+
| ItemId | ItemDescription |
+--------+-----------------+
|      1 | Item 1          |
|      2 | Item 2          |
|      3 | Item 3          |
+--------+-----------------+
```

**Stock:**

```
+----------+--------+-----+
| BranchId | ItemId | Qty |
+----------+--------+-----+
|        1 |      1 |  23 |
|        1 |      2 |  35 |
|        1 |      3 |  12 |
|        2 |      1 |  28 |
|        2 |      2 |   5 |
|        2 |      3 |  76 |
|        3 |      1 |  87 |
|        3 |      2 |   2 |
|        3 |      3 |  46 |
+----------+--------+-----+
```

Given that, you should be able to extrapolate this example for X number of branches:

```
SELECT ItemDescription, IsNull([Branch 1],0) as [Branch 1], IsNull([Branch 2],0) as [Branch 2], IsNull([Branch 3],0) as [Branch 3]
FROM   
(
    SELECT i.ItemDescription, b.BranchName, Sum(IsNull(s.Qty,0)) Qty
    FROM Stock s
    INNER JOIN ItemMaster i ON s.ItemId = i.ItemId
    INNER JOIN BranchMaster b ON s.BranchId = b.BranchId
    GROUP BY i.ItemDescription, b.BranchName
) t 
PIVOT(
    SUM(Qty) 
    FOR BranchName IN (
        [Branch 1], 
        [Branch 2], 
        [Branch 3])
) AS pivot_table
ORDER BY ItemDescription
```

It is possible to have a dynamic number of columns, but it gets more complicated.